# How to pre-select phone code based on country select in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I like to have a Country select dropdown and based on Country select, the below input box for phone number should automatically pre-select the mobile number code.

So, that I'll save the phone number country code and Country.

I've seen this plunker `plnkr.co/edit/DYyfGj?p=preview` , but it's not like what I'm trying to achieve.

This is what I've tried so far :

**HTML :**

```
<select ng-model="country" 
    ng-options="country.name for country in countriesWithPhoneCode" 
    >
    <option value="">Select country</option>
  </select>

  {{country}}
```

Currently the above code lists the countries. Based on the selection i need to pre-populate the dial code for next input.

here's my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/zmTmpgCJ70N0MOO2UW4U?p=preview

Comment: So what is your problem? How far did you get? What is it that you are stuck with? Please show us your code..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more precise on what you acually want to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Mike  Update the code.

Comment: Demo seems to work fine...what is the exact problem? You need to advise what expected results are that differ from current

Comment: I myself found the answer for my question :P

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the question,

https://plnkr.co/edit/sbWy7xOKWSzdDZuY2xWk?p=preview

```
Country : <select ng-model="country" ng-options="country.name for country in countriesWithPhoneCode">
              <option value="">Select country</option>
          </select>
<br/><br/>
Phone :   <input value="{{country.dial_code}}" disabled/>
          <input ng-model="phone"/>
<br/>

{{country.name}} - {{country.dial_code}} {{phone}}
```

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp',
    []);

app.controller('countryCtrl', [
        '$scope',
function($scope) {

$scope.countriesWithPhoneCode = [
{
"name": "Afghanistan",
"dial_code": "+93",
"code": "AF"
},
{
"name": "Aland Islands",
"dial_code": "+358",
"code": "AX"
},
{
"name": "Albania",
"dial_code": "+355",
"code": "AL"
},
{
"name": "Algeria",
"dial_code": "+213",
"code": "DZ"
},
{
"name": "AmericanSamoa",
"dial_code": "+1684",
"code": "AS"
},
{
"name": "Andorra",
"dial_code": "+376",
"code": "AD"
},
{
"name": "Angola",
"dial_code": "+244",
"code": "AO"
},
{
"name": "Anguilla",
"dial_code": "+1264",
"code": "AI"
},
{
"name": "Antarctica",
"dial_code": "+672",
"code": "AQ"
},
{
"name": "Antigua and Barbuda",
"dial_code": "+1268",
"code": "AG"
},
{
"name": "Argentina",
"dial_code": "+54",
"code": "AR"
}
];

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="countryCtrl">
  Country : <select ng-model="country" ng-options="country.name for country in countriesWithPhoneCode">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
  </select>
<br/><br/>
 Phone : <input value="{{country.dial_code}}" disabled/>
<input ng-model="phone"/>
<br/>
{{country.name}} - {{country.dial_code}} {{phone}}
</body>

</html>
```